# How to decapsulate tunnel and forward inner packets

Tags: linux, networking, gre

I am trying to decapsulate tunneled packets arriving at port `eth0` and forward them decapsulated to another port `eth1` on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine like this:

```
                                  ____________
         10.40.16.0/24           |            |
----(e.g. GRE, VXLAN tunnel)---->|eth0        |
                                 |     \      |
                                 |      tun0  |
           10.0.1.0/24           |     /      |
<---------(inner traffic)--------|eth1        |
                                 |____________|
```

I am flexible when it comes to the tunneling protocol (e.g. VXLAN or GRE).
The likely challenge is that the encapsulated packets are not intended for the server, but to be forwarded.

My question is:
Is this possible on Linux with tools such as OpenvSwitch, tc, iptables etc.?
If yes, i would appreciate any minimal working example or any other help.
If no, am I possibly overlooking a quirky aspect of the network stack in the Linux kernel?

I have tried multiple approaches e.g. using Openvswitch, tc.
Here is my `tc` example:

```
IINF=${1:-eth0}
OINF=${1:-eth1}

ip link set dev ${IINF} up
ip link set dev ${OINF} up
ip link set dev ${IINF} promisc on
ip link set dev ${OINF} promisc on

ip link add vxlan0 type vxlan dstport 4789 external
ip link set dev vxlan0 up
ip link set dev vxlan0 promisc on

tc qdisc add dev ${IINF} handle ffff: ingress
tc qdisc add dev vxlan0 handle ffff: ingress

tc filter add dev ${IINF} parent ffff: protocol all u32 match u8 0 0 action mirred ingress redirect dev vxlan0

# see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-tunnel_key.8.html
tc filter add dev vxlan0 protocol all parent ffff: flower enc_dst_port 4789 action tunnel_key unset action mirred egress redirect dev ${OINF}
# Filter rule is somehow not triggered.

# This would simply forward the tunneled traffic, but not decapsulate it.
# tc filter add dev vxlan0 protocol all parent ffff:  u32 match u8 0 0 action mirred egress redirect dev ${OINF}
```

In this example e.g. the second filter rule for decapsulation would not be hit.
I have working examples for the exact opposite case, i.e. encapsulating any traffic coming into `eth0` with `tc` or `openvswitch`.
However, i seem to overlook something for the decapsulation.

Possible pitfalls:

- rp_filter
- incorrect checksums
- iptables blocking traffic
- incorrect MAC addresses (inner and outer)

Comment: This seems an incredibly complex setup for something Linux *already does by default.* What's the "tun0" in your diagram? Why promisc? Why tc?

Comment: It works perfectly by default, when the packet is processed locally like e.g. an ICMP packet. However, i struggle to forward the inner packets, if there are not meant for the server.
The tun0 can be any tunnel interface (gre/vxlan). The Dst MAC addresses of the tunnel are not necessarily, the ones of the server. Therefore the promiscous mode to avoid that packets are being dropped. 
Why tc? Again this is just an example what i tried. I have also tried using openvswitch or the native Linux routing.

Comment: Promisc is the wrong tool; it works at MAC layer (preventing the host from dropping packets with wrong destination MAC) but even then it doesn't force the host to *process* the IP packets inside, only makes them visible at "raw socket" level and that's that. But the encapsulated packets *are* meant for your host, so promisc is irrelevant either way. And if you're using GRE, which doesn't even carry MAC addresses in the first place, promisc on the tunnel isn't even an option.

Comment: As i said, the destination MAC address of the tunnel, so the outer MAC addresses, are not necessarily the ones of my server, due to my setup. Therefore the promiscuous mode. You are right, this has no effect on the inner packets. 
Maybe one misunderstanding: The encapsulated packets *are not* meant for the server.

Comment: Do you mean the inner or outer packets?

Comment: The inner packets or in other words the packets inside the VXLAN/GRE tunnel are not meant for the server.
By the way, thank you for your interest in this question!

Comment: In that case, this is a completely normal situation and the promisc option is useless. It would only be relevant if the _outer_ packets (i.e. the tunnel header) were addressed to a different system. In your case though, whether the packets arrive over a physical connection or whether they're decapsulated from a tunnel, the host will forward them according to their destination IP – routers don't need promisc mode in order to do that.

Comment: My issue is not the promisc mode. 
The issue is that the inner packets are *not routed* to eth1 even after i set route e.g. `ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 dev eth1` (see above figure). 
I know what you mean and my naive assumptions was also that the packet *should* be routed by Linux. However, this is for some unknown reason not the case, therefore my question here. 
With the words of Linus Torvalds "Talk is cheap, show me the code". I would appreciate any minimal working example (bash script, commands). I will test it and report back with as much details as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable forwarding, so your system behaves as a router and not a simple host?

Comment: Yes. 
`$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1`